# Why am I getting an error logging in after setting up Unity Dependency Injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, unity-container

I'm building a site with C# ASP.NET using MVC5 and EF6. I have just set up a separate project for the database model and a separate project as the Data Access Layer with the repositories in.

I am now getting the following error when I attempt to login to the site:

```
The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.
```

The line which fires the error is:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

My UnityConfig file registers the following types:

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
container.RegisterType(typeof(IUserStore<ApplicationUser>), typeof(UserStore<ApplicationUser>));
container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationUserManager>();
container.RegisterType<SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>, ApplicationSignInManager>();
container.RegisterType<DbContext, BlogModelContainer>();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
```

I'm thinking I'm missing another line here, but haven't managed to work it out yet. Is it possibly something to do with the `DefaultConnection` I need to include?

This worked before I started putting Unity into the project. Any help appreciated. Let me know if I need to include any other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Basically if you're going to use Unity with MVC5, you need to use the correct Nuget package.

I had accidentally used the Unity.Mvc package when I should have used Unity.Mvc5. After correcting this, things worked as I had expected (this tutorial was also useful for what I was doing, but not essential http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/).